# Excel : How to output a list of data that satisfies a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of numbers (single column), A,
and two values B and C which are calculated from the list of data, A.

I would like to output all data A in the same sheet (but in a different column) that is out of the range B and C, that is, "A less than B" and "A more than C".

How do I do this?

Say I have set of data(A):

```
108.466
108.459
108.427
108.436
108.422
108.416
108.387
108.398
108.388
108.377
108.385
108.378
108.355
108.378
108.418
108.414
108.322
108.327
108.344
108.278
108.266
108.285 etc,
```

And By using

```
=AVERAGE(B:B)-(NORMSINV(0.995))*SQRT(((COUNT(B:B)/(COUNT(B:B)-1)*VAR(B:B)))/COUNT(B:B))
```

and

```
=AVERAGE(B:B)+(NORMSINV(0.995))*SQRT(((COUNT(B:B)/(COUNT(B:B)-1)*VAR(B:B)))/COUNT(B:B))
```

To obtain my confidence intervals, B and C (for the significance level of 0.05% - thus, the NORMSINV(0.995).

B and C are single values, they apply to the whole data set (of A).I'd like to print in a separate column, all values that do not lie in the confidence interval, ie, (A less than B) and (A more than C).

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Very sorry, @DavidPostill, I have added more information to my question. I can't get seem to get the Format Text as a Table utility to work, but I've attached a photo of what I'm trying to get. So far I've been trying to use INDEX and SMALL in the function (I looked these up online), but I don't have a very good grasp of advanced functions like these and I can't seem to get the result I need. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You're welcome. Much better ;) It's now a good question that can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data  like:

[image]

In cols **A, B, C**, In **D1** enter:

```
 =IF(OR(A1<B1,A1>C1),1,"")
```

In **D2** enter:

```
 =IF(OR(A2<B2,A2>C2),1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down.  Column **D** marks the rows of interest.

Then in **E1** enter:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy down.  Column **E** lists the values in column **A** that are "out of bounds":

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To use two fixed cells *(say B9 and C9)*  rather than all of columns **B** and **C** as criteria, change the formulae in column **D** as follows:

**D1 and D2 and below:**

```
 =IF(OR(A1<$B$9,A1>$C9),1,"")
 =IF(OR(A2<$B$9,A2>$C$9),1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! If B and C are single values, (just 1 cell, how would I go about this?) very sorry if I am asking an obvious question, I am quite new to advanced excel formulas/functions. 

Let _B_ and _C_ as the cells in question,

I assume it would be 
=IF(OR(A1<_B_,A1>_C_),1,"")
and
=IF(OR(A2<_B_,A2>_C_),1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")

but will this affect any other part of the function?

Thanks again!

Comment: @JoshuaChin  See my **EDIT#1**